# $a>0$, & let $x$ be a real number. Prove that if $\{r_n \}$ is decreasing rational sequence with limit $x$, then $a^x=\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a>0$, and let $x$ be a real number. Prove that if $\{r_{n} \}$ is any decreasing rational sequence with limit $x$, then $a^x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{r_n}$

Where in the book $a^x$ is defined as $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{s_n}$ where $ \{ s_n \}$ is an increasing sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\{-r_n\}$ is an increasing sequence of rationals that converges to $-x$

Using the definition of your book, we know that:
$$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^{-r_n}=a^{-x}>0$$

Since the limit is positive, thus:
$$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a^{r_n}=a^{x}$$

Comment: I see how you got $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a ^{\r{n}} = a^{-x} > 0$ but I don't know why it implies the second part thanks.

Comment: Take the multiplicative inverse of both sides

Comment: hmm, still unsure. If I take the inverse of the first line then we get $(lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a^{r_{n}}) \cdot a^{x} =1$ Or should I look at the inverses of the actual sequence terms?

Comment: The inverses of the actual terms of the sequence (you can take their inverse becasue they are non zero)

Comment: Okay,so since we know that the $\{ -r_n \}$ sequence has an invertible limit, and that each element of the sequence is invertible we know that the limit of the sequence of the inverses has the limit that is the inverse of$\{ -r_n \}$'s limit ? Is this a commonly proved statement? I think it can be prove using the limit rule for limits maybe,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since $2x-r_n$ is increasing and

$$\lim_n 2x-r_n=x$$

we have

$$a^x=\lim_n a^{2x-r_n}=\lim_n \frac{a^{2x}}{a^{r_n}}= \frac{a^{2x}}{\lim_n a^{r_n}}  \,.$$

Multiply both sides by $\frac{\lim_n a^{r_n} }{a^x}$